# Encrypt the FormURL varaible on form Submission

Tags: marketing-cloud, ampscript, encryption

I have create the contact us cloud page using the ampscript, created two cloud page one is the main page which pre-populate the form values and on form submission it will redirect to thank you page were the data processing is done and values are submitted in MC DE and Salesforce CRM.

On clicking the submit button url is set `@FormURL = Concat("https:/thankyou_Backlog?**Id=**", **@contactId**)`  I want to encrypt the url parameter i.e @contactID so that it do not display in the url as it is.

Thank you!!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of passing a direct link, use the CloudPagesURL() function to redirect to the second CloudPage:

```
@FormURL = CloudPagesURL(123,”Id”,@contactID)
```

Above will append an encrypted query string to the url.

Read more here: https://ampscript.guide/cloudpagesurl/

Comment: Thank you, that worked for me.